# Windows Azure Access Control & WPF?

Tags: asp.net, wpf, azure, appfabric, claims

Anyone has worked with Windows Azure Access Control & WPF Client? I like authentication of Zune Client with Live ID.

I need authenticate with Windows Live ID in my WPF app.

I have a Website that works with Windows Azure Acces Control , I use claims for Roles in my website , but i need know, if its possible use this claims with WPF app.

I can´t find anything  about WPF  & Windows Azure Access Control , only for ASP.NET

Thank you so much.!

Comment: I found a solution for this :) via nuget http://nuget.org/packages/Azure.ACS.LoginControls i hope it's useful for someone.

Comment: Check out this question, [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7640529/how-to-develop-user-authenticated-rest-service-with-azure-acs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7640529/how-to-develop-user-authenticated-rest-service-with-azure-acs) The answer links to a MSDN sample for Windows Phone. Although it is targeted for Silverlight, the principles apply to WPF as well. You may also find the explanation / diagrams of [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh446531.aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh446531.aspx) helpful.

Comment: @RicardoPons, please post this as an answer to your own question so that other people could easily find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you might look at this it explains about it.

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/4656.wpf-application-with-live-id-facebook-google-yahoo-open-id.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [this](http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/C-SkyDrive-API-via-Live-3f2ce65f) could help you. I found it in [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/messengerconnect/thread/e57eabe4-bd87-4e30-adea-a2c5c9c52d8c) post

Answer (score 0):

First of all try the link I m sending you ... It will provide you the basic structure of how to setup your live ID : [MSDN blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/brunoterkaly/archive/2012/04/25/windows-azure-access-control-service-understanding-the-security-buzzwords.aspx)

You can also try this one to read more : [MSDN library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg185915.aspx)